# Obtain a basis of invertible matrices for $M_n(D)$, where $D$ is an integral domain

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

> Let $D$ be an integral domain. Prove that $M_n(D)$ has a basis consisting of $n^2$ invertible matrices.

Consider $M_n(D)$ as a $D$-module. Define invertible elements $V_{nn}=I_n$, $V_{n-1,n-1} = V_{nn} - E_{nn} + E_{n-1,n} + E_{n,n-1}$, $V_{ii}$ considered as permutation $(n,n-1,\dots,i+2,i+1)$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n-2$, and $V_{ij}=I_n+E_{ij}$ for $i\ne j$. I don't know how to prove they are linearly independent.

Comment: What do you mean by n2. Do you perhaps mean $n^2$? Also...

Comment: It would be useful if you could tell us what you have tried. This helps us to understand what you already know so we can better focus our help. Also, people around here get touchy when people just post a question without motivation etc. as they are unwilling to simply do others homework for them, moreover they dislike it when a third party steps in and does the homework for them anyway so questions like this which merely states a question tend to get closed (pending adding more info). Adding in what you have tried and where you came across it will stop your question getting closed in this way.

Comment: Do you know what a basis is?

Comment: considering Mn(D) as a D-module. defined invertible elements Vnn=In and Vn-1,n-1 = Vnn - Enn + En-1,n + En,n-1 and Vii was considered as permutation (n,n-1,...,i+2,i+1) for i=1,2,...,n-2 , but I don't know how to prove linearly independent?

Comment: and Vij=In+Eij for i≠j

Comment: What do you mean by "$V_{ii}$ considered as permutation"? Permutation of the columns of $I_n$?

Comment: Vii is a Permutation of the rows of In.

Comment: the row of i+1 sit down instead of the row of i+2 and the row of i+2  sit down instead of row of i+3 ,..., and row of n sit down instead of the row of i+1.

Comment: The question is very interesting, tough poorly written...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by $E_{i,j}$ you mean the matrix in $M_n(D)$ with $1$ at the place $i,j$ and $0$ otherwise. Then we have the following:

- $V_{n,n}=I_n=\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}\,;$
- $V_{n-1,n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E_{k,k}+E_{n-1,n}+E_{n,n-1}\,;$
- $V_{i,i}=\sum_{k=1}^iE_{k,k}+\sum_{k=i+2}^nE_{k,k-1}+E_{i+1,n}\,,\ \style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{for}}\ i=1,\dots,n-2\,;$
- $V_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}+E_{i,j}\,,\ \style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{for}}\ i\ne j\,.$

Other than $V_{n-1,n-1}$, all the matrices $V_{i,j}$ are clearly invertible (they are permutation matrices if $i=j\ne n-1$ and triangular with $1$s at the diagonal if $i\ne j$), and $V_{n-1,n-1}$ is the block matrix $I_{n-2}\oplus\binom{1\ 1}{1\ 0}$, so it is invertible as well.

Let $a_{p,q}\in D$ be such that $\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{q=1}^na_{p,q}V_{p,q}=0$. We want to show that $a_{p,q}=0$ for each $p,q$. Using the equalities above we can rewrite this equality as

$$\begin{align*}0=&\,\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}V_{p,q}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}a_{i,i}V_{i,i}+a_{n-1,n-1}V_{n-1,n-1}+a_{n,n}V_{n,n}\\
=&\,\quad\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}\biggl(\,\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}+E_{p,q}\,\biggr)\\
&\,\ +\ \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}a_{i,i}\biggl(\,\sum_{k=1}^iE_{k,k}+\sum_{k=i+2}^nE_{k,k-1}+E_{i+1,n}\,\biggr)\\
&\,\ +\ a_{n-1,n-1}\biggl(\,\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E_{k,k}+E_{n-1,n}+E_{n,n-1}\,\biggr)\\
&\,\ +\ a_{n,n}\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}\,.\tag{$\boldsymbol{\ast}$}
\end{align*}$$

We know that the matrices $E_{i,j}$ are $D$-linearly independent, so our next task is to rewrite the sum above as a $D$-linear combination of the matrices $E_{i,j}$. Clearly the most tractable terms are those involving the matrices $E_{k,k}$. The total contribution of these terms is precisely

$$\begin{align*}
&\,\quad\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}\,\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}\,+\,\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}a_{i,i}\,\sum_{k=1}^iE_{k,k}\\
&\,\ +\ a_{n-1,n-1}\,\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E_{k,k}\,+\,a_{n,n}\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}\\
=&\,\quad\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}\,\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}\,+\,\sum_{i=1}^na_{i,i}\,\sum_{k=1}^iE_{k,k}\\
=&\,\quad\sum_{k=1}^n\Biggl(\,\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}\,\Biggr)\,E_{k,k}\,+\sum_{k=1}^n\Biggl(\,\sum_{i=k}^na_{i,i}\,\Biggr)\,E_{k,k}\\
=&\,\quad\sum_{k=1}^n\Biggl(\,\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}\,+\sum_{i=k}^na_{i,i}\,\Biggr)\,E_{k,k}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Since the matrices $E_{k,k}, k=1,\dots,n$ are $D$-linearly independent, it follows that

$$\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}\,+\sum_{i=k}^na_{i,i}=0,\ \style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{for}}\ k=1,\dots,n\,.$$

From this we conclude that for $r=1,\dots,n-1$ the coefficient $a_{r,r}=0$: just take $k=r$ and $k=r+1$ in the equality above and subtract. This in turn implies the equality

$$\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}\,+a_{n,n}=0\,,\tag{$\boldsymbol{\ast\!\ast}$}$$

and even better, the original equation $(\boldsymbol{\ast})$ simplifies to

$$\begin{align*}
0=&\,\quad\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}\biggl(\,\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}+E_{p,q}\,\biggr)\,\ +\ a_{n,n}\sum_{k=1}^nE_{k,k}\,,
\end{align*}$$

and thanks to this big simplification it is clear now that the contribution of the terms $E_{p,q}$ with $p\ne q$ is precisely

$$\sum_{\substack{1\leq p,q\leq n\\p\ne q}}a_{p,q}E_{p,q}\,,$$

from which we conclude that $a_{p,q}=0$ for all $p,q$ with $p\ne q$. Finally, applying this result on equality $(\boldsymbol{\ast\ast})$ above we conclude that the pending coefficient, namely $a_{n,n}$, is $0$ as well. This proves that the matrices $V_{i,j}$ are $D$-linearly independent, even if $D$ is not a domain.

Comment: If  $D$ is a field, then the above matrices form a basis for $M_n(D)$. Does this hold for $D$ a commutative ring? (The relations you got strongly suggest that this is the case.)

Comment: @user Yes, indeed: see for example Corollary 4.4 of David Eisenbud's book *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*.