# Can we find a basis of $\Bbb P^{n\times n}$ whose element are all invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Can we find a basis of $\Bbb P^{n\times n}$ whose element are all invertible? Here $\Bbb P$ is a field.

The classical $E_{ij}$, each of which are singular. Oh.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000662/does-there-exist-a-basis-for-the-set-of-2-times-2-matrices-such-that-all-basis for the case $n=2$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes: we can always find a basis of $\mathbb{P}^{n\times n}$ which is non-singular.

Let $E_{ij}$ denote the standard elements comprising a (singular) basis of $\mathbb{P}^n$.  As Mike F pointed out in his answer on Geoffrey's linked MSE question, it is sufficient to show each $E_{ij}$ can be written as a linear combination of invertible matrices.

To start, simply note that $E_{12} = (E_{12}+ I) - I$ is a linear combination of invertible elements.

Now select two [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $P$ and $Q$, where $P$ is any permutation matrix swapping $1$ and $i$ and $Q$ likewise swaps $2$ and $j$. Then $E_{ij} = PE_{12}Q$, so, $E_{ij} = P(E_{12} + I)Q - PQ$ is a sum of invertible elements.